# PHP class Degin - help needed

Tags: php

I am trying to create a class but would like to ask which will be the best way to do this.

from this website the user can Book an Event and these Events are organized by different Organizers.
for example if i book an event AAAA from Orginizer ZZZ it is possible that diffrent conditions apply
on me to as if i Book the same event event from another Organizer.

e.g. Orginizer ZZZ has different payment methods, different seatings, different menues etc but in some case these can also be same.

My web search provides OrganizerID and depending on this ID I have to display these infos.

Now my question do i need an interface? order any guideline to implement this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read up on the basics of OOP and what a class is actually modelling..

When you have got this straight you can start to think about the paradigms you are going to need to implement you solution.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php